# Uploading a file to firebase storage returns 403 error despite changing database rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I am creating a basic web page using HTML and JS to upload gifs into  my firebase storage.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Upload gifs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
    <input type="file" valu="upload" id="fileButton"></input>

  </body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "",
          authDomain: "",
          databaseURL: "",
          projectId: "",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: "",
          appId: "",
          measurementId: ""
        };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    console.log(firebase);

    var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
    var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
      var file = e.target.files[0];

      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('gifs/' + "123");

      storageRef.put(file);

      task.on('state_changed', 
        function progress(snapshot) {
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;
        }
        ,
        function error(err) {

        }

      )
  })

    </script>
</html>
```

My rules for my firebase db are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Despite this when I run the code, it returns a 403 error saying its forbidden. I am not sure why as the rules have been changed to allow access to the database but I still have the issue. Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the security rules of [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), one of the database services offered by Firebase, with the rules for [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

You will find the documentation for Cloud Storage security rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security

In your case, since it seems from your question that you want to allow anyone to read and write, you would write your Cloud Storage rules as follows:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```